# WordPress WooCommerce - Disable "my account" screen and allow users to go to wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When you install WooCommerce, a new page is created called "My Account".
[image]

When subscriber level users attempt to go to any admin page, including the user's profile at `/wp-admin/users.php` they get redirected.

Cannot access this screen with WooCommerce as a subscriber:
[image]

**How can I disable this behavior? What are the filters or hooks that need to be changed?**

Comment: Are you sure you aren't viewing this on your admin account?

Comment: Yes. How can a SUBSCRIBER get to that screen?

Answer (score 0):

This is meant to redirect users with "customer" role to a custom URL

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'custom_login_redirect');
 
function custom_login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {     
    if ( wc_user_has_role( $user, 'customer' ) ) {
        $redirect = get_home_url(); // homepage
        //$redirect = '/custom_url'; // custom URL same site
    }  
    return $redirect;
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to the question. :) We're not talking about a login redirect. There is a persistent re-direct for the entire admin area for subscribers after Woo is installed.